# WordPress content layout with Bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to pull wordpress content to the grid structure created with Bootstrap. But I don't want to create separate query for each column. How can I pull content from the same category in a single query? My codes are as follows.I want to show the last 3 items added

```
 <div class="container">
  <?php query_posts('showposts=3&orderby=date&cat=1'); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
  
      <img src="" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
      <img src="" class="img-fluid mb-3 rounded" alt="...">
      <img src="" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
  </div>
  </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
```

[what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U94TV.png)

Comment: You need to increment your loop. This has definitely been answered before.

Comment: When I create separate queries, all three show the same content as the contents are in the same category. Is there a way to show different content in the same category? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/: _"Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible."_ - so you should rather not be using this one to begin with. If this is for a single page where it doesn't matter if the main query gets executed first and then the result discarded, you should use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`

Comment: _"How can I pull content from the same category in a single query?"_ - your query parameters _already_ do that - you simply need to process the result differently. Rather than looping over it, you should access the elements in an array, like `get_posts` would get you, purposefully via their index, and then insert the data in the places of the HTML structure, where you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <?php $i = 1; query_posts('showposts=3&orderby=date&cat=1'); ?>
        <div class="col-8">
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if($i==1){ ?>
          <img src="" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
        <?php } elseif($i==2){ ?>
          <img src="" class="img-fluid mb-3 rounded" alt="...">
        <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
      <?php } $i++; endwhile; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could there be a problem with the else part? Shows the same content 2 times in the right column

Comment: check again. resolved

Answer (score 0):

[click the picture for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6qrT.png)

else created a problem. Also the 2 contents in the right column are the same. I wanted it to be different.